# Point which minimizes the squared sum distances to edges of a triangle

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles

I need to find coordinates of a point at which the sum of the squared distances to each of the three lines that form a triangle is minimized.

It seemed to me that the point is the triangle's incenter, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you have the coordinates of the corners, you can write down explicit formulas for the _signed_ distance to each side (they will be simple affine functions of $x$ and $y$). Square them and add, producing a second-degree polynomial in $x$ and $y$ -- then find the bottom point by setting each partial derivative to zero.

Comment: Do you mean the distance to the side (a line segment) or the distance to the line (ie the length of the perpendicular from the point to the line)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant. I need to minimize the distances of the point to each side, so the lengths of the perpendiculars to the sides.

Comment: @nikolamilekic The distinction is relevant for an obtuse triangle only: sometimes the distance to a line segment is not measured by orthogonal projection; the distance to an infinite line always is.

Comment: Now I understand. I need the distances to the lines. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Justpassingby Thanks a lot for the answer. Why did you delete it?

Comment: Because it was incorrect :-) I am trying to update it but I already know that the incentre is *not* the answer.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856796/how-to-prove-the-property-of-the-lemoine-point-of-a-triangle

Comment: @almagest That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! I need more help however. I'm not a mathematician, and everything I've found online for the point is a bit cryptic. :( How do I calculate the point's coordinates programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_i,y_i)$ denote the coordinates of the $i$-th vertex and $d_i(x,y)$ the function given by the signed distance to the side (as an infinite line) opposite the $i$-th vertex:

$$d_1(x,y)=\frac{(x_2-x_3)y-(y_2-y_3)x-y_3x_2+y_2x_3}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2}}$$

and similar for $d_2$ and $d_3$ by circular permutation of indices (i.e., the sign of the distance is only arbitrary the first time, and then it is fixed for the two other lines). The quantity in the denominator can be abbreviated to $L_1$ ($L_2$, $L_3$) as it is the length of the side opposite the $i$-th vertex.

Then the partial derivatives that Henning refers to are

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(d_1^2+d_2^2+d_3^2)
=2d_1\frac{y_3-y_2}{L_1}+2d_2\frac{y_1-y_3}{L_2}+2d_3\frac{y_2-y_1}{L_3}$$

and similar for the $y$-derivative. So one way of expressing the problem as as a linear system in two variables is

$$\eqalign{
d_1\sin\alpha_1+d_2\sin\alpha_2+d_3\sin\alpha_3&=&0\\
d_1\cos\alpha_1+d_2\cos\alpha_2+d_3\cos\alpha_3&=&0
}$$

where $\alpha_i$ is the anticlockwise oriented angle between the positive $X$ axis and the edge opposite the $i$-th vertex, the orientation of the latter edge being determined by circular permutation of vertices.